# Запрос - вывести верхнее и нижние значения дат в группе за период действия группы

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть набор данных вида:

```
MyID DStart     DEnd
001  01.12.2013 30.04.2014
001  01.05.2014 04.11.2015
006  05.11.2015 20.12.2015
001  21.12.2015 31.12.2015
001  01.01.2016 29.02.2016
006  01.03.2016 30.09.2016
006  01.10.2016 20.03.2019
006  21.03.2019 31.12.2020
```

Нужно сгруппировать по коду, но по каждой группе показать только верхнее и нижние значения дат. У группы есть период ее действия, определённый значениями DSTART и DEND. Период действия группы заканчивается, если изменится код следующего временного интервала, и здесь начинается период действия новой группы.

Правильно:

```
001 01.12.2013  04.11.2015
006 05.11.2015  20.12.2015
001 21.12.2015  29.02.2016
006 01.03.2016  31.12.2020
```

Выборка вида:

```
select a.MYID, a.D1, a.D2
  from (select V.MYID,
               Min(V.DSTART) keep (dense_rank first order by DSTART) over (partition by V.MYID) d1,
               Max(V.DEND) keep (dense_rank last order by DEND) over (partition by V.MYID) d2
      from V
      order by DSTART) a
group by MYID, D1, D2;
```

не корректна, т.к. выдает минимум и максимум по всей таблице, без учета что одинаковый ID выпадает в различные периоды.

Так будет неправильно:

```
MYID    D1          D2
001     01.12.2013  29.02.2016
006     05.11.2015  31.12.2020
```

Пример входных данных:

```
create table v (myid number, DStart date, DEnd date);
INSERT INTO v VALUES('001', to_date('12/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('04/30/2014','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('001', to_date('05/01/2014','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('11/04/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('006', to_date('11/05/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('12/20/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('001', to_date('12/21/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('12/31/2015','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('001', to_date('01/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('02/29/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('006', to_date('03/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('09/30/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('006', to_date('10/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('03/20/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'));
INSERT INTO v VALUES('006', to_date('03/21/2019','mm/dd/yyyy'), to_date('12/31/2020','mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: select min.... union all select max...

Comment: *по каждой группе показать только верхнее и нижние значения дат.* Т.е. выбрать записи, где либо DStart минимально, либо DEnd максимально?

Comment: У группы есть период ее действия DSTART и DEND, если за период ее действия группа изменилась на какой-либо срок, то эта новая группа будет показана внутри первоначальной группы. DSTART на 1 больше DEND предыдущей группы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу такой запрос:

```
with data (code, ds, de) as (
    select '001', date'2013-12-01', date'2014-04-30' from dual union all 
    select '001', date'2014-05-01', date'2015-11-04' from dual union all
    select '006', date'2015-11-05', date'2015-12-20' from dual union all
    select '001', date'2015-12-21', date'2015-12-31' from dual union all
    select '001', date'2016-01-01', date'2016-02-29' from dual union all
    select '006', date'2016-03-01', date'2016-09-30' from dual union all
    select '006', date'2016-10-01', date'2019-03-20' from dual union all
    select '006', date'2019-03-21', date'2020-12-31' from dual
)
select code, min (ds) ds, max (de) de
from (
    select q.*, sum (chng) over (order by ds) grpnum 
    from (
        select d.*,
            case 
            when coalesce (lag (code) over (order by ds), code) = code then 0 
            else 1 end chng
        from data d
    ) q
) q
group by code, grpnum
order by ds    
;
```

Вывод:

```
COD DS         DE        
--- ---------- ----------
001 2013-12-01 2015-11-04
006 2015-11-05 2015-12-20
001 2015-12-21 2016-02-29
006 2016-03-01 2020-12-31
```

Идея здесь:
Сначала найти строки, где изменяеттся группа и пометить их флагом `chng=1`.
Затем, накапливающимся суммированием этого флага выделить группы.
Остаётся только сгруппировать и вывестии мин./макс. как начало и конец периода.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT MyID, DStart xDStart,
                     CASE WHEN myID = LAG(myID) OVER (ORDER BY DStart) THEN NULL ELSE DStart END DStart,
                     CASE WHEN myID = LEAD(myID) OVER (ORDER BY DEnd) THEN NULL ELSE DEnd END DEnd
              FROM v
              ),
    cte2 AS (SELECT *
             FROM cte
             WHERE COALESCE(DStart, DEnd) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT DISTINCT myID, 
                COALESCE(DStart, LAG(DStart) OVER (ORDER BY xDStart)) DStart,
                COALESCE(DEnd, LEAD(DEnd) OVER (ORDER BY xDStart)) DEnd
FROM cte2
ORDER BY 2;
```

Проверено на https://livesql.oracle.com/ - ответ вроде верный.

Comment: 001 01.01.2016 29.02.2016 => 001 21.12.2015 29.02.2016

Comment: @sergsh Посмотрите... вроде нигде не ошибся. За оптимальность не ручаюсь, есссно.