# Непрерывные временные интервалы для группы

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Есть данные о периоде нахождении оборудования (`tid`) в торговой точке (`tp`).
 Одна единица оборудования может быть сперва в торговой точке `А`, потом в торговой точке `В`, а затем вернуться в торговую точку `А`. Нужно получить периоды, в течение которых оборудование **непрерывно** находилось в торговой точке.

Пример исходных данных:

```
tp  tid   dt_open       dt_close  
A   1     01.02.2018    20.05.2018  
A   1     21.05.2018    05.06.2018  
A   1     11.06.2018    01.01.3001  
B   1     06.06.2018    10.06.2018  
C   2     01.04.2018    02.05.2018  
C   2     03.05.2018    25.06.2018
```

Для данного набора данных, ожидаемый результат:

```
tp  tid   dt_open       dt_close  
A   1     01.02.2018    05.06.2018  
B   1     06.06.2018    10.06.2018
A   1     11.06.2018    01.01.3001
C   2     01.04.2018    25.06.2018
```

Есть понимание, как это сделать с помощью PL/SQL: отсортировать по `tid` и `dt_open` и потом построчно в цикле сравнивать по `tid` и `tp`, самый очевидный вариант.

Но можно ли это сделать именно средствами SQL? Есть идеи?

Comment: Посмотрите оконные функции: lead или lag, исключаете, если разница больше 1 день и находите первый и последний день из оставшихся. Как и pl/sql.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976431. Попробуйте , если будут затруднения - спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно сравнить - предыдущий день, было ли это вчера, если нет, то изменить группу. Попробуйте так:

```
with ppd (tp, tid, dt_open, dt_close) as (
    select 'A', 1, date'2018-02-01', date'2018-05-20' from dual union all 
    select 'A', 1, date'2018-05-21', date'2018-06-05' from dual union all
    select 'B', 1, date'2018-06-06', date'2018-06-10' from dual union all
    select 'A', 1, date'2018-06-24', date'3001-01-01' from dual union all
    select 'C', 2, date'2018-04-01', date'2018-05-02' from dual union all
    select 'C', 2, date'2018-05-03', date'2018-06-25' from dual
)
select tp, tid, min (dt_open) dt_open, max (dt_close) dt_close
from (
    select q.*, sum (chng) over (partition by tp, tid order by dt_open asc) rnk
    from (
        select ppd.*,
            case 
            when coalesce (
                lag (dt_close) over (partition by tp, tid order by dt_open asc),
                dt_open - 1) = (dt_open - 1) then 0 
            else 1 end chng
        from ppd
    ) q
) q
group by tp, tid, rnk
order by tid, dt_open 
;
```

Вывод:

```
TP        TID DT_OPEN    DT_CLOSE  
-- ---------- ---------- ----------
A           1 01.02.2018 05.06.2018
B           1 06.06.2018 10.06.2018
A           1 24.06.2018 01.01.3001
C           2 01.04.2018 25.06.2018
```

Comment: Да, для данного набора данных это более правильное решение, но реальный набор данных у меня немного "кривоватый", встречаются пересекающиеся интервалы для одного и того же tid.  Поэтому остановился на варианте сравнения по tp, ну и исключил из case сравнение по tid, т.к. это учтено уже в условии parttion by.

Comment: Да, с гапами и пересечениями, эта было бы совсем другая задача. И посмотрите где у вас выражение `order by`, во внутреннем подзапросе оно ни имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение:

```
with ppd as (select *from (
select 'A' as tp, '1' as tid, cast('01.02.2018' as date) as dt_open, cast('20.05.2018' as date) as dt_close from dual  
union
select 'A' as tp, '1' as tid, cast('21.05.2018'as date) as dt_open, cast('05.06.2018' as date) as dt_close from dual
union
select 'B' as tp, '1' as tid, cast('06.06.2018' as date) as dt_open, cast('10.06.2018' as date) as dt_close from dual
union
select 'A' as tp, '1' as tid, cast('11.06.2018' as date) as dt_open, cast('01.01.3001' as date) as dt_close from dual
union
select 'C' as tp, '2' as tid, cast('01.04.2018' as date) as dt_open, cast('02.05.2018' as date) as dt_close from dual
union
select 'C' as tp, '2' as tid, cast('03.05.2018' as date) as dt_open, cast('25.06.2018' as date) as dt_close from dual) order by tid, dt_open)

select d2.tp, d2.tid, min(dt_open), max(dt_close)
from (select d1.*,
           sum(cng) over(partition by d1.tid order by d1.tid, d1.dt_open) as grp_num
      from (select d.*,
                   case
                     when coalesce(lag(d.tp)
                                   over(partition by d.tid order by d.tid,
                                        d.dt_open),
                                   d.tp) = d.tp then
                      0
                     else
                      1
                   end cng
              from ppd d
             order by d.tid, d.dt_open) d1) d2
group by d2.tp, d2.tid, d2.grp_num;
```